# Calculate the mean of several values within the same row in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mean

I have this `df` with several rows that have more than one value in the Percent column. Some rows have only one single value and some rows will have 2 - 3 values. I would like to calculate the mean for rows with more than one value.

```
    location            Ethnic                          Percent
0   Beaches-East York   English , Scottish , Canadian   19.7 , 18.9 , 24.2
```

Since only 4 rows have multiple values, I am doing in a very amateur way by calculating it row by row and replace the values. What is a more efficient way to do it if I have 50 rows to calculate?

**My amateur attempt:**

```
import statistics

print(statistics.mean([19.7,18.9,24.2]))
```

Comment: Are you reading these data from excel file?

Comment: @Leosky No. Data is from website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use apply function in percent column to do it

```py
df["mean_percent"] = df.Percent.apply(lambda x: pd.np.mean([float(p) for p in  x.split(",")]))
print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks this works! And for those who are looking to round it `df["mean_percent"] = df.Percent.apply(lambda x: pd.np.mean([float(p) for p in  x.split(",")]).round())`